# How to change "nextcell" function in this script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thanks in advance for helping. So I am currently using the Google Apps Script to create auto timestamp whenever a specific cell is being edited. It works great and I got it from browse the internet. However, I am currently in the need to modify it but I don't really understand how.

So, currently the script work by detecting any column that we set with number and it will make the timestampt next to the column that we set, can we customize the timestamp sheet? I want to change it to the most left column. Because currently I have to put the timestamp on the third column and it's not really match the way it should be. Date should be on the most left side. How to make the auto timestamp work on the other column instead of always next to the column that we set as a source?

The script:

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Unified Tracker" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97e3s.png)

I haven't tried anything and expecting to change the location of the auto-timestamp column

Answer (score 0):

From `I want to change it to the most left column.`, when your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
```

#### To:

```
var nextCell = r.offset(0, -1);
```

- By this modification, when the cell of column "B" is edited, `new Date()` is put into column "A" of the edited row.
- In your script, I think that `r` is the edited cell of column "B". In this case, `offset(0, 0)` are `offset(0, 1)` are the columns "B" and "C", respectively. When you want to put the value to column "A", `offset(0, -1)` can be used.

#### Reference:

- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)

Comment: @Almighty Kid Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `Thank you so much for helping and answering!`, I couldn't understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend to read more about the [Range.offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#offset(Integer,Integer,Integer)) method and some other methods of the Range class, and about [onEdit(e) trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=ru#onedite) as well. Further we may expect, that a user can modify more than 1 cell at once and there should appear all corresponding timestamps in the leftmost column (i.e. column A) in this case. Right?

As a result I recommend the code below:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var editedRange = e.range, startCol = editedRange.getColumn();
  // Do not write timestamps for other sheets
  if (editedRange.getSheet().getName() != 'Unified Tracker') return;
  if (startCol == 1) return;  // reserve column A for timestamps
  // Set target range to A column cells
  var targetRange = editedRange.offset(0, 1 - startCol, editedRange.getHeight());
  targetRange.setValue(new Date());
}
```

Please note, you should replace the name 'Sheet1' with your sheet name.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping and answering! May I know if I can activate this timestamp function on other sheets on the same file?

Comment: Sure, you can activate timestamp feature for all other sheets by removing (or commenting) the code line which ends with `return;` word.